# Embed a script from github in wordpress posts

Tags: html, wordpress

I use github to backup and share my scripts.  I'd like to be able to post some of these on my blog.  Is it possible to embed a script (and syntax hightlight it if possible) into my wordpress blogs?  [This](https://github.com/Gen2ly/scripts/blob/master/.scripts/pspvidconv) is just one of them I'd like to do.  Any thoughts be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do this myself.   Pointing out GitHub Gist it looks like is the best solution.  Since gists are repositories, I learned I can update them and hence scripts on my blog will be updated.  I wrote a script for it and posted it [here](http://linuxtidbits.wordpress.com/2012/06/07/embedded-scripts-in-wordpress-with-github-gist-and-update-script/).  Thanks for the help/comments guys.

Answer (score 0):

Something like https://gist.github.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/embed-github-gist/
and
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/screenshots/

Comment: Is there a way embed the [raw link](https://raw.github.com/Gen2ly/scripts/master/.scripts/pspvidconv)?  I was hoping that updated versions on github would show up on the blog.

Comment: I can't find a plugin that does that specifically